# Передача видео по сети

Tags: mfc, c++

Поднимаю вопрос снова
[ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/183827/c-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-mfc)

Как передавать видео по сети? Разбивать на кадры или  потоками какими?
Язык С++ библиотека MFC

Comment: Поставьте на сервер [VideoLAN](http://videolan.org) и транслируйте что угодно и как угодно. HTTP, RTSP, Unicast, Multicast.... На вскидку вам нужен VOD(video on demand), гуглите на эту тему.   
В вашей программе-сервере понадобится запускать vlc (если не запущен) и коннектиться к нему по telnet или http.

Писать с нуля свой велосипед не стоит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое - какой тип видео Вы собираетесь передавать?
Советую Вам обратить внимание на Орen source библиотеку liveMedia ([www.live555.com](http://www.live555.com)).
Это С++ библиотека, которая распространяется согласно лицензии LGPL и реализует поддержку различных протоколов потокового видео (RTSP, RTP/RTCP).

Желаю успеха...